# How To Stop a Stuck Pod in Kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cicd

**Background**

I am trying to learn to automate deployments with Jenkins on my laptop computer. I did not check the resource settings in the helm chart when I deployed Jenkins and I ended up over provisioned the memory and cpu requests.

The pod was initializing for several minutes and then eventually ended up in the status of CrashLoopBackOf.

**Software and Versions**

```
$ minikube start
  minikube v1.17.1 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19042 Build 19042
...
...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.20.2 on Docker 20.10.2
...
```

Note that Docker was installed from Visual Studio Code with Docker Desktop and Windows 10 WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS enabled.

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.5.2", GitCommit:"167aac70832d3a384f65f9745335e9fb40169dc2", GitTreeState:"dirty", GoVersion:"go1.15.7"}
```

**Installation**

```
$ helm repo add stable https://charts.jenkins.io

$ helm repo ls
NAME                    URL
stable                  https://charts.jenkins.io


$ kubectl create namespace devops-cicd
namespace/devops-cicd created

$ helm install jenkins stable/jenkins --namespace devops-cicd

$ kubectl get svc -n devops-cicd -o wide
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE    SELECTOR
jenkins         ClusterIP   10.108.169.104   <none>        8080/TCP    7m1s   app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=jenkins
jenkins-agent   ClusterIP   10.103.213.213   <none>        50000/TCP   7m     app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=jenkins


$ kubectl get pod -n devops-cicd --output wide 
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
jenkins-0   1/2     Running   1          8m13s   172.17.0.10   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

The pod failed eventually, ending with the status of CrashLoopBackOff

Unfortunately, I forgot to extract the logs for the pod.

In full disclosure, I got it deployed successfully by pulling the chart to my local file system and halved the size of the memory and cpu settings.

**Questions**

I fear that the situation of over provisioning in the Production environment one day. So how does one stop a failed pod from respawning/restarting and undo/rollback the deployment?

I tried to set Deployment replicas=0 but it had no effect. Actually, the only resources I could see were a couple of Services, the Pod itself, a PersistentVolume and some secrets.

I had to delete the namespace to remove the pod. This is not ideal. So what is the best way to tackle this situation (i.e. just deal with the problematic pod)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you scale the deployment to 0 then 0 pods should be presented. Kubernetes couldn't terminate the pod. It can happen for different reason. If you `kubectl edit pod-name`, you will see `finalizers`. Manually removing them will allow the pod (or other objects) to be deleted. Same for `kubectl edit deployment name` and set resources. If you mean how to **delete** stuck pod, then the answer is above. The pod is not even running, you can't stop it.

Comment: If the pod is named `something-0` then it might be managed by a StatefulSet and not a Deployment.  If you're using Helm, you can use `helm rollback` to undo a `helm upgrade`, which can help the "production deploy has gone wrong" scenario.

Comment: Previously, I checked everything except StatefulSet. I studied the helm chart, it is indeed that the pod is scheduled using StatefulSet.  I deleted everything and installed the original helm chart again. Yes, I could delete the pod/StatefulSet, `$ kubectl delete statefulset jenkins -n devops-cicd
statefulset.apps "jenkins" deleted`. Interesting things I have noticed though. There weren't any logs for the pod. I couldn't rollback or delete the helm release because there was none. I guess this type of installation I need to do it in a dedicated namespace so it can be cleaned up in isolation

Answer (score 2):

Drawing on the feedback I have gathered and confirmed that the pod is scheduled by a `StatefulSet`. I am attempting to answer my own question with the hope that it is useful for newbies like me.

My question was how to stop a pod (from respawning).

So here I get the info on the StatefulSet:

```
$ kubectl get statefulsets -n devops-cicd -o wide
NAME      READY   AGE   CONTAINERS              IMAGES
jenkins   0/1     33s   jenkins,config-reload   jenkins/jenkins:2.303.1-jdk11,kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:1.12.2
```

Then scale in:

```
$ kubectl scale statefulset jenkins --replicas=0 -n devops-cicd
statefulset.apps/jenkins scaled
```

Result:

```
$ kubectl get statefulsets -n devops-cicd -o wide
NAME      READY   AGE     CONTAINERS              IMAGES
jenkins   0/0     6m35s   jenkins,config-reload   jenkins/jenkins:2.303.1-jdk11,kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:1.12.2
```